# How to use a lookup function to create a new column in Pandas dataframe based on multiple column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, lookup

I'm kind of new to Python so apologies in advance if there's anything missing information that would help, or if I use the wrong terminology in some places.

I'm using Google Colab, and I have 20 csv files, one for each current Premier League team, with details of every match they have played this season. I upload them, and then perform some calculations on them before concatenating the data into one big dataframe.
The code is as follows:

```
#upload each team's csv file to colab environment
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()

#create function to perform cumulative average calculations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunction(team):
  df_team = pd.read_csv(team)
  df_team['cum_avg_xG'] = df_team['xG'].expanding().mean()
  df_team['cum_avg_GF'] = df_team['GF'].expanding().mean()
  df_team['cum_avg_GA'] = df_team['GA'].expanding().mean()
  df_team['cum_avg_shots'] = df_team['Sh'].expanding().mean()
  df_team[['cum_avg_xG', 'cum_avg_GF', 'cum_avg_GA', 'cum_avg_shots']] = df_team[['cum_avg_xG','cum_avg_GF', 'cum_avg_GA', 'cum_avg_shots']].shift(1, freq=None, axis=0)
  df_team = df_team.reset_index(drop=True)
  return df_team

#combine tables to create one big dataframe
import glob
import os

path = '/content/' 
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "*.csv"))

team_temp = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = myfunction(filename)
    team_temp.append(df)
df_allteam = pd.concat(team_temp, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df_allteam
```

The table below is a partial representation of the dataframe with the vital information only, and with made up data for simplicities sake

| Date | Team | Opposition | cum_avg_xG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 26/08/2022 | Man City | Bournemouth | 1.6 |
| 2/09/2022 | Man City | Arsenal | 1.65 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 26/08/2022 | Bournemouth | Man City | 0.85 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2/09/2022 | Arsenal | Man City | 1.45 |

'cum_avg_xG' is the Team's average xG(Expected Goals) up to the match on that date

We can see that with the way I have each team's match data as a separate csv file, we have some duplicates (e.g. Man City vs Bournemouth on 26/08/2022 is the same as Bournemouth vs Man City on 26/08/2022)

Using this, I want to essentially create a new column called 'opposition_cum_avg_xG', which would contain the value for the opposition's 'cum_avg_xG' value, which we already have in the table. Using the Man City vs Bournemouth example, in the row where Bournemouth are the oppostion, I want this column to include the 'cum_avg_xG' for Bournemouth (which would be 0.85). Bear in mind I would also have to do this for the other columns I calculated (which you can see from the code, e.g. 'cum_avg_GF'), but for now I am just focusing on one column

| Date | Team | Opposition | cum_avg_xG | opposition_cum_avg_xG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 26/08/2022 | Man City | Bournemouth | 1.6 | 0.85 |
| 2/09/2022 | Man City | Arsenal | 1.65 | 1.45 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 26/08/2022 | Bournemouth | Man City | 0.85 | 1.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 2/09/2022 | Arsenal | Man City | 1.45 | 1.65 |

Now I think this would require some sort of lookup function? I have tried looking online for some help but I haven't found anything that might help. The complication here is that the lookup would be based on more than one column, from the same dataframe? (The Date and Opposition are both needed in order to get the correct value needed for the new column)

One possibility I considered was creating a separate dataframe with just Date, Team and cum_avg_xG, and using lookup from that, but again from there I would be unsure on how to proceed

Comment: You can perform a merge on itself but with the team and opposition columns swapped.

Comment: @Andreas Wong: our fellow answers correctly, the way to think in pandas is to `merge`. Using `vlookup` in Excel is just another way of merge reference table to the main table